# Find all angles in a triangle, given 2 internal 90deg angles and segment equality.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Given the triangle ABC, with  $\measuredangle ABC > 90^\circ $, points D and E are on AC, such that [AD] = [DE] = [EC] and $\measuredangle ABE = 90^\circ $ and $\measuredangle DBC = 90^\circ $.

Find the measures of the angles in triangle ABC.

(Source: Romanian Math Magazine (Gazeta Matematica)).

---

I tried denoting angles BAC and BCA with x and y, but I seem to be going in circles.
Also tried to construct the height from B, and use the height theorem for right angled triangles, without getting to the result.

Comment: Are you sure about "points D and E are on BC" ?

Comment: Fixed! Thanks! The points split the long edge in 3 equal parts.

My intuition is that the triangle has angles 30, 30, 120; but not sure how to go about the proof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$BD$ is a median in the right triangle $ABE$, hence $BD = AD = DE$; $BE$ is a median in the right triangle $DBC$, hence $BE = DE = EC$. Therefore $BDE$ is an equilateral triangle.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Wonderful! I didn't know this property ... just looked up for the proof:

$ m_B = \frac{2 * (a^2 + c^2) - b^2}{4} $

And for a triangle, with right angle B,  m_B is half of the hypothenuse.

Comment: Or you could "complete the rectangle" to see that the median is half the diagonal.

Answer (score 1):

Found an alternate solution, for those not knowing the theorem :)

Construct EF perpendicular on BC; then, triangles ECF and DCB are similar (not sure the English term for triangles with proportional edges), becaue EF || BD; so, F is the middle of BC; EF is both median and height => BE = EC.

Then, follow the same logic to show BDE is equilateral.